# jquery make one div follow anothers position

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm having trouble here with my script... I have this cart image and when you click on it a div appears and it has a arrow I would like that div to follow where the cart image is all the time because when you add another menu item the cart image moves and looks like the one image below...
[image]

You see how the arrow is pointing at the magnifine glass instead of the shopping cart is because I added a new menu item. Now here is the script im using and what it does.

```
$(document).ready( initialise );

function initialise() {
var myObject = $(".cart-toggle");
var myposition = myObject.offset();
$("#cart").css({'margin-left' : myposition.left });

}
```

Here is what it looks like now.
[image]

Im not sure why its going over there I just want the arrow under the cart image... Thank you !

Comment: I appreciate the code provided, but it's hard to debug without supporting html/css. Maybe a live example/jsfiddle?

Comment: its alot of html and css would you like a link ?

Comment: Call function like this `initialise();` [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/7nLpL/)

Comment: @derek_duncan http://testing.webznap.com

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are going to need to edit some of your css, but the cart needs to be absolutely positioned and the offset needs to be recalculated correctly.

```
$(function() {
  var el = $('.cart-toggle');
  var cart = $('#cart');
  var pos = el.offset();
  var cW = cart.outerWidth();
  var left = (pos.left - cW/2) + 'px';

  cart.css({
    'left' : left,
    'position' : 'absolute'
  });
});
```

Comment: okay i just added the script and its messing up again its adding negative px ?

Comment: im sorry to do this but do you think you could just make the arrow move ? instead of the cart ?

Comment: its the .panel:before i really apprecitate you help

Comment: yep. hope it helped some

Comment: so how would i do it for just the panel:before ?